# remove gridview selector column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm sure the answer to this question is incredibly obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to remove the "selector" column from the default winforms gridview. (The column the red arrow is pointing at).

[image]

I've tried programmatically removing the column `gridview.Columns[0].Remove` but that just removed my first data column. It doesn't show up in the "column collection" also, and I've played with all the settings that looked somewhat promising.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the `RowHeadersVisible` to `False` in the GridView (it's a property)

Comment: Weird...I don't see that property anywhere.

Comment: @Mansfield sorry, it's called RowHeaderVisible - amended my answer. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible.aspx

Comment: Haha I found it just before I checked your post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mansfield LOL. It's been loooong since I don't do Winforms but I knew it was something like that ;)