# This area of DataGridView called as?

Tags: c#, datagridview

What is name of following area in `DataGridView`? Can I do something with this area (like changing caption)? Is there are `events` for this area?

[image: DataGridView]

Comment: I believe its possible to double-click that to select all cells, not sure if it has a name though

Comment: This question might be helpful if you're looking to remove it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12376264/1324019 I don't know that you can natively do anything else with it though.

Comment: @Sayse Yes, it selectt all cell in Grid on single also.

Comment: Selecting a row will select that row, I'm pretty sure that top square will select *all* cells

Comment: Yes this select all cell, but I never thought about its name...

Comment: @Sayse A single click is enough to select all cells

Comment: ah fair enough, I've never needed to use the double click events of a datagrid

Comment: That is called `TopLeftHeaderCell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That portion is called as `TopLeftHeaderCell`

Even datagridview provides you a property named [TopLeftHeaderCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.topleftheadercell.aspx)

You can change the content of that cell via following code

```
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "abc";
```

To capture click event of that cell capture `CellClick` event and handle `e.ColumnIndex = -1` and `e.RowIndex = -1`

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            //TopLeftHeaderCell clicked
        }
  }
```

If you want to use the `RowHeaderCell` try this

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "1";
```

this will allow you to show numbers like `Row Number`